# Mongo OLAP tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

In my application I'm using Ruby on Rails and MongoDB via Mongoid. I need to do some datamining and create OLAP cubes.
Is there any tools for OLAP or I need to do it manually?

Comment: Just as version: you can use any olap system (for example, MS SSAS) with mongodb .net drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know OLAP tools for mongodb.

It will be just my opinion, but if you need OLAP - mongodb is not good choice.
OLAP is needed for structured data (dimensions, facts and so on), but the main advantage of mongo is unstructured data.

Answer (score 0):

To update a bit the responses: you could use MongoDB as your main source of data and then prepare/extract some data for specific reporting. E.g., [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) is now supporting [MongoDB](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/ds_mongodb.html) for this kind of usage. It makes no sense to extract the whole set of data but most of the time data for the reporting and analytics represent only a fraction of the whole and it makes sense to connect an in-memory OLAP tool for reporting and analytics.